# Why is one installation of IE8 (unexpectedly) loading pages from cache, while others are not?

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-8, forms-authentication

I have website that is ASP.NET with Forms Authentication, clicking the logout button does correctly call FormsAuthenication.SignOut() so it invalidates the cookie.

All machines in the office are using IE8 and work fine, just like Firefox. But one installation of IE8 will load cached copies of authenticated pages even after logging out when navigating using links on the pages instead of automatically being redirected to the login.aspx for attempting to reach a secured resource.

If they attempt to do any postback or refresh the page it will correctly redirect them but I don't understand why this is occuring, I can't reproduce this does anyone else have any idea what could cause and how to stop it?

Comment: This definitely does not belong to SuperUser. I think stackoverflow would be a better site (if not, serverfault.com)

Comment: Too bad my old vote still counted. Given the author's comments (and the new title I gave it), this actually should be on Super User... And then there's also yesterday's duplicate "IE8 incorrectly loading cached page for asp.net" from the same author at SF; http://serverfault.com/questions/81361/ie8-incorrectly-loading-cached-page-for-asp-net Impatience creates a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Internet Options->General->Browsing History Settings and make sure that "Check for new versions of stored pages" isn't set to "Never".

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably no longer relevant; just leaving it here for a while for the comments. (And the HTTP response headers might still give some clue.)

---

Seems to me that IE8 might in fact be working as expected here...

- What do the HTTP response headers say about caching? See, for example, Firebug's "Net" panel in Firefox, or Web Inspector's "Resources" panel in Chrome or Safari.
- Any `<meta>` tag with caching details?

Comment: I disagree that it's working as expected, if it was working as expected this would be a consistent behavior across machines, not specific to one machine. It's really like navigating to the pages it doesn't even make a request to the server to check if the page is expired. I could understand if the issue was with using back buttons but it's for actively using the website. There are no meta keywords to try to force any caching behavior

Comment: If the server tells the browser it can cache a page, then not asking the server anything is just fine. So: what about the headers as sent by the server (which should be the preferred way to set caching anyhow)?

Comment: As for *specific to one machine* -- so, *For one of the machines in the office, IE8 will [..]* means that the other machines use IE8 as well?

Comment: Yes, the machines are all IE8, this issue only occurs on one specific machine. No other machines exhibit this behavior, and of course Firefox doesn't as it always just works correctly.